# get product name using json in android app

Tags: android, json, android-layout, listview, android-activity

I have shopping cart program and I want to get product names using json from php file.
I can get the the json successfully from PHP file but when I put it in this class its not working and when I run the app it show nothing as name in listview !
here is part of the code:

```
public static List<Product> getCatalog(Resources res){
        System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + CatalogActivity.name1);
        if(catalog == null) {
            catalog = new Vector<Product>();
            catalog.add(new Product(name1, res
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.deadoralive),
                    "Dead or Alive by Tom Clancy with Grant Blackwood", 29.99));
            catalog.add(new Product("Watchmen", res
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.watchmen),
                    "Watchmen by Alan Moore and Dave Gibbons", 14.99));


        }

        return catalog;
    }



public void ListDrwaer() {
        List<Map<String, String>> productList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();


        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("products");


            //  System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(0));

              pro1 = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(1);
            pro2 = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(2);
            name1 = pro1.getString("name");
            //    System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + data);


            System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + pro2);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

The code get the name1 string well but It don't show it in the listview...
I need to do something which it get the name1 from the web first, put it in getCatalog class and then make the listview and show the content...
how can I do that?

Comment: I don't see any code for refreshing the listview after adding items which could be the reason that UI is not updated for  you. pls refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJQmvRHF5xg

Comment: getCatalog is public static class... and when i use notifyDataSetChanged i got“Non-Static method 'notifyDataSetChanged()' cannot be referenced from a static context”, how should I solve this ?!

Comment: yes you need to make getCatalog as non-static. why you need a static method?